# Incomplete model translation status information for .rvt translations

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I've been testing out model translations with .rvt files of various sizes. Recently my model translation jobs never get to a 'completed' status as described in the documentation, even though the underlying webhook information and shows that the translation is completed.

In my local testing, I have a node script that uploads the .rvt file to forge storage and starts an SVF2 translation. I have tried this with both SVF and SVF2 and have the same issue. In order to get Room and Space information, I have the `generateMasterViews` flag set to `true`. I also have `x-ads-force` set to true so that the translation always re-runs. After starting the translation, my script checks the translation status every 5 seconds until the `status` property of the translation is `'success'`. Lately, my script has not been finishing because the translation status never comes back with `'success'` and instead hangs at `'90% complete'`. See response below.

Additionally, I have a forge webhook with the `extraction.updated` and `extraction.finished` events registered. The `extraction.finished` event never fires, however the final `extraction.updated` event contains all the information that would indicate a completed translation. See response below.

This only appears to be an issue for URNs that have had translations run at least once before, however it has not always been an issue. It started occurring a week or two ago. If I upload a file to a new storage path (e.g. by prefixing the uploaded filename with a timestamp) the job status completes as expected.

Translation status response

```
{
  "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzLzE2MTI4MDgzNjA1MjNmb3JnZV90ZXN0X3NtYWxsLnJ2dA",
  "derivatives": [
    {
      "hasThumbnail": "true",
      "children": [
        {
          "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzLzE2MTI4MDgzNjA1MjNmb3JnZV90ZXN0X3NtYWxsLnJ2dA/output/Resource/model.sdb",
          "role": "Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase",
          "mime": "application/autodesk-db",
          "guid": "6fac95cb-af5d-3e4f-b943-8a7f55847ff1",
          "type": "resource",
          "status": "success"
        },
        {
          "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzLzE2MTI4MDgzNjA1MjNmb3JnZV90ZXN0X3NtYWxsLnJ2dA/output/Resource/AECModelData.json",
          "role": "Autodesk.AEC.ModelData",
          "mime": "application/json",
          "guid": "a4aac952-a3f4-031c-4113-b2d9ac2d0de6",
          "type": "resource",
          "status": "success"
        },
        {
          "phaseNames": "New Construction",
          "role": "3d",
          "hasThumbnail": "true",
          "children": [
            {
              "guid": "92b5dec7-790a-45b0-a5e8-cd9f76058c3a-00056e47",
              "type": "view",
              "role": "3d",
              "name": "3D",
              "status": "success",
              "progress": "complete",
              "camera": [
                135.5139617919922,
                -135.10296630859375,
                149.049560546875,
                -4.035602569580078,
                4.446601867675781,
                9.5,
                -0.40824830532073975,
                0.40824830532073975,
                0.8164966106414795,
                1.5180892944335938,
                0,
                1,
                1
              ]
            },
            {
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzLzE2MTI4MDgzNjA1MjNmb3JnZV90ZXN0X3NtYWxsLnJ2dA/output/Resource/3D View/3D/3D1.png",
              "role": "thumbnail",
              "mime": "image/png",
              "guid": "c70aa596-d404-714f-6795-9276087c3800",
              "type": "resource",
              "resolution": [100, 100],
              "status": "success"
            },
            {
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzLzE2MTI4MDgzNjA1MjNmb3JnZV90ZXN0X3NtYWxsLnJ2dA/output/Resource/3D View/3D/3D2.png",
              "role": "thumbnail",
              "mime": "image/png",
              "guid": "6ef65d1a-4a59-111d-f1ec-4e543bd2712b",
              "type": "resource",
              "resolution": [200, 200],
              "status": "success"
            },
            {
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzLzE2MTI4MDgzNjA1MjNmb3JnZV90ZXN0X3NtYWxsLnJ2dA/output/Resource/3D View/3D/3D4.png",
              "role": "thumbnail",
              "mime": "image/png",
              "guid": "2c06739e-5164-4f6d-450e-c8833fd2a2ba",
              "type": "resource",
              "resolution": [400, 400],
              "status": "success"
            }
          ],
          "success": "90%",
          "name": "3D",
          "guid": "f2cf4f10-55b9-4f4b-7c03-9f1cf7d2e689",
          "progress": "90%",
          "type": "geometry",
          "viewableID": "92b5dec7-790a-45b0-a5e8-cd9f76058c3a-00056e47",
          "status": "inprogress"
        },
        {
          "phaseNames": "New Construction",
          "role": "3d",
          "hasThumbnail": "true",
          "children": [
            {
              "guid": "c884ae1b-61e7-4f9d-0001-719e20b22d0b-00056e5e",
              "type": "view",
              "role": "3d",
              "name": "New Construction",
              "status": "success",
              "progress": "complete",
              "camera": [
                39.99827575683594,
                -36.743263244628906,
                52.14657211303711,
                -2.148294448852539,
                5.40330696105957,
                10,
                -0.40824830532073975,
                0.40824830532073975,
                0.8164966106414795,
                1.0748299360275269,
                0,
                1,
                1
              ]
            },
            {
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzLzE2MTI4MDgzNjA1MjNmb3JnZV90ZXN0X3NtYWxsLnJ2dA/output/Resource/3D View/08f99ae5-b8be-4f8d-881b-128675723c10/New Construction/New Construction1.png",
              "role": "thumbnail",
              "mime": "image/png",
              "guid": "a3c19573-8948-7ae0-fb5c-75cab1d0e87a",
              "type": "resource",
              "resolution": [100, 100],
              "status": "success"
            },
            {
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzLzE2MTI4MDgzNjA1MjNmb3JnZV90ZXN0X3NtYWxsLnJ2dA/output/Resource/3D View/08f99ae5-b8be-4f8d-881b-128675723c10/New Construction/New Construction2.png",
              "role": "thumbnail",
              "mime": "image/png",
              "guid": "86d53dd2-82c8-1948-5997-00ebf6078ed7",
              "type": "resource",
              "resolution": [200, 200],
              "status": "success"
            },
            {
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzLzE2MTI4MDgzNjA1MjNmb3JnZV90ZXN0X3NtYWxsLnJ2dA/output/Resource/3D View/08f99ae5-b8be-4f8d-881b-128675723c10/New Construction/New Construction4.png",
              "role": "thumbnail",
              "mime": "image/png",
              "guid": "7e36c074-8997-d941-4dc3-6a72fcdf3b9b",
              "type": "resource",
              "resolution": [400, 400],
              "status": "success"
            }
          ],
          "success": "90%",
          "name": "New Construction",
          "guid": "37992551-4555-5430-58a0-9158b794a411",
          "progress": "90%",
          "type": "geometry",
          "viewableID": "c884ae1b-61e7-4f9d-0001-719e20b22d0b-00056e5e",
          "status": "inprogress"
        }
      ],
      "name": "1612808360523forge_test_small.rvt",
      "progress": "90% complete",
      "outputType": "svf2",
      "status": "inprogress"
    }
  ],
  "hasThumbnail": "true",
  "progress": "90% complete",
  "type": "manifest",
  "region": "US",
  "version": "1.0",
  "status": "inprogress"
}
```

Webhook `extraction.updated` payload:

```
{
  "URN": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzL2ZvcmdlX3Rlc3Rfc21hbGwucnZ0",
  "Payload": {
    "status": "success",
    "scope": "12f35ced-3397-40c9-a7dc-bd80bddbbca6",
    "bubble": {
      "progress": "complete",
      "owner": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzL2ZvcmdlX3Rlc3Rfc21hbGwucnZ0",
      "region": "US",
      "type": "design",
      "children": [],
      "guid": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzL2ZvcmdlX3Rlc3Rfc21hbGwucnZ0",
      "startedAt": "Mon Feb 08 18:04:15 UTC 2021",
      "hasThumbnail": "true",
      "status": "success",
      "success": "100%",
      "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bGF5ZXJfbW9kZWxzL2ZvcmdlX3Rlc3Rfc21hbGwucnZ0"
    },
    "registerKey": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked our engineering team to look into the logs and this is what they replied. "The manifest status is 'now' 100% complete. It was a SVF2 job, it took about 3 minutes for SVF2 generation. I guess that’s we were seeing “job was suck”.

```
    "hasThumbnail": "true",
    "progress": "complete",
    "type": "manifest",
    "region": "US",
    "version": "1.0",
    "status": "success"
```

"

I also tried your scenarios and was not able to reproduce the problem, so I am not really sure what to tell you. If you see more problems like this in future, please reach out to me directly at cyrille at autodesk .com